# how to produce a list in netlogo that every item meets its especial condition

Tags: list, random, range, netlogo, genetic-algorithm

I wanna produce several lists in NetLogo that every item on the list is randomly in a special range. for example, I want a list with 3 items where the first item is randomly between 4 to 10 , the second item randomly between 10 to 30 and the third item between 12 to 35 ...can anyone help me?
ex : randomly produce theses lists :
[5,15,16] ,[4,12,34],[9,25,31] ,etc

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? For example, what you've tried so far, what your input looks like, and an example (not a description) of what your desired output should look like for a given input?

Comment: I am working on a genetic algorithm to improve the staff allocation of an emergency department .hence ,I am looking for producing a chromosome .for this , I have considered a list with the length of staff types(doctors,nurses,...).there are minimum and maximum limitation for the number of staff.(e.g .we can have 4 up to 10 doctors)so the items of the list I produce must meet these limitations .

Comment: suppose my hospital is consist of doctors,nurses and auxiliaries .we can have 4 up to 10 doctors ,10 up to 30 nurses ,12 up to 35 auxiliaries .to determine the optimum number , I want to produce random lists like [4,12,14],[6,25,17] ,etc as the first population .
actually I don't know how to produce a list that every item of it ,satisfy the mentioned constraints .

Comment: You need to edit your question, comments are not formatted the same way and are hard to read. Also, StackOverflow is intended to be a question and answer repository, so all the relevant information should be in the question to assist anyone in the future with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to first define this:

```
to-report random-in-range [a b]
  report a + random (b + 1 - a)
end
```

Then you can:

```
(list random-in-range 4 10
      random-in-range 10 30
      random-in-range 12 35)
```